# Permissions error (#200) when posting a comment using facebook graph api

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-php-sdk, facebook-graph-api-v2.2

I have an application with every permission enabled and the only user of it as an admin. I'm trying to enable functionality so that way it can post comments. I am successful with Facebook Graph API Explorer, but when I attempt to implement the same technique either in code or through the facebook api explorer utility I get the following error:

"Permissions 200 error"

using facebook's Graph API Explorer (at https://developers.facebook.com/tools/explorer/), this works via the POST method:

872650956119411_885219084862598/comments?message=ContentForTheComment

However, when I attempt the same thing either with code or by using the tool's dropdown box to change the application from Graph Api Explorer to my app,  I get a permissions error and it will not work. The app has every permission request that graph api explorer does (and then some), and the only user is also an admin of the app. Changing the scope of the feed post from 'friends' to 'public' has no effect, either.

As a side observation, when I attempt (via the Graph API Explorer tool) to make the same POST request, but with the app token in lieu of the access token  (for my app) it gives:

"message": "(#200) User must have accepted TOS",

What is with this error code and what am I doing incorrectly? I don't even know where the TOS is or how to agree to it.

Answer (score 0):

So I filed a bug report with facebook and one of their reps helped me figure it out. Here's the answer for anyone else who may be searching to no avail:

"It's important to make sure that you only use app-scoped user IDs in the app they were generated for. Also, when you're trying to take an action on a post (e.g. commenting) you should only use post IDs that you found using your access token in your app, e.g. by calling me/feed. Can you try with user and post IDs from your app and let me know if it works?"

so,

Posting with the app and then commenting on that post worked!. :D :D